# Ionic 3: Promise is not working on some Android devices

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic3, es6-promise

I’m using Promise in my ionic function **loadScript**, and when I test on browser it’s OK, when I test on some devices android 4.x.x it’s OK, but when I test on my Lenovo K5 Note (Android 5.1),
the Promise doesn’t work and Exactly the debug alerts that my android 5.1 fired are:

```
alert('0');
alert('1');
alert('inside promise');
alert('return promise');
```

So it ignores the promise core instructions including:

```
alert('script loaded');
```

Below you will find the source code + ionic info

## Home.ts:

```
//imports + Decorators
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private platform:Platform,
              private geolocation:Geolocation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    alert('0');
    this.loadScript()
    .then( () => {
      alert('initMap1');
      this.initMap();
      alert('initMap2');
    })

    .then( () => {
      console.log('geolocation');
      alert('geolocation')
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.getGeolocation();
      },5000);
      alert('geolocation end')
    })

    .then( () => {
      alert('end all');
      console.log('end all');
    })    

  }

  loadScript(){
    alert('1');
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          alert("inside promise");
        console.log("Async Work Complete");
          console.log('start1');
          var script = document.createElement('script');

          script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBtYmf_L2ESZVcnkeIHRw_uD0VQIBbFYAM&libraries=places";
          console.log('append3');
          document.head.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
          script.onload = function () {
            console.log('resolved');
            alert('loaded script');
            resolve();
          };  
    });
    alert('return promise');
    return promise;  

  }

  initMap() {
//Implementation of initMap()
    alert('map Loaded');
  }

  getGeolocation(){
    //geoLocation implementation
  }

}

}
```

## ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.7.1 
    OS                : Linux 4.13

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : xxx
Misc:

    backend : pro
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.7.1 
    OS                : Linux 4.13

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME  : xxx/Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: I guess you are expecting the alert('loaded script'); to show before promise return, is that correct? if so you need to wait until that's executed.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Yes That's What I want, how to wait, would you post a response please

Comment: Advice: Don't use `alert()` to debug async code. Reason being `alert()` introduces another source of asynchronism and code with alerts isn't guaranteed to behave the same as code without alerts.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 : Thank you!